# Error in sending message from an Node.js app to Slack channel

Tags: node.js, slack-api, slack

Trying to send message to slack from Node.js app

I have used following package https://github.com/xoxco/node-slack

For Detailed reference full source code is in https://github.com/sudanvellakovilkanakavel/attendence-app

I couldn't understand

1. what is hook_url
2. How to define it

Error output

> ```
> CJBTDLDD0003:backend kanaks$ node readingFile.js
> /Users/kanaks/Desktop/backend/readingFile.js:2
> var slack = new Slack(hook_url,options);
>                       ^
>
> ReferenceError: hook_url is not defined
>     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/kanaks/Desktop/backend/readingFile.js:2:23)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
>     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
>     at startup (node.js:136:18)
>     at node.js:966:3
> ```

My Code

```
var Slack = require('node-slack');
var slack = new Slack(hook_url,options);

//var slack = new Slack(hook_url,{proxy: http_proxy});

//Trying to send message to slack from Node.js app
//I have used following package https://github.com/xoxco/node-slack

slack.send({
  text: 'Meassage from node.js app to slack!',
  channel: '#attendance',
  username: 'Bot'
});

var fs = require("fs");
//reading the file
fs.readFile('Attendance01-04-2016.dat','utf8',function (err,data){
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err);
  }
  //spliting each line
  var lines = data.split("\n");
  //storeing in array and printing the file
  for (i=0;i<=lines.length;)
  {
    console.log(lines[i]);
    i=i+1;
  }
});
```

Comment: `hook_url` you need to get from Slack.

Comment: You mean something like var Slack = require('node-slack');